# How use pixel shader to achive smooth text?

Tags: java, android, text, libgdx, pixel-shader

I want to have smooth text in my game. I found that solution is pixel shader, so i do every thing like is described on  [github documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts) . I've got font.vert and font.frag files and in this documentation is said that i should use const float smoothing  = 0.25f / (spread * scale). My font is 48 px size  thus i use 0.25f/48.0f but my font is stil sharp and ragged. What am i doing wrong  ?

this is font.frag :

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 0.25/48.0 ;

void main() {
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha);
}
```

I alos use linear filter for my font:

```
arial_white_48.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,  TextureFilter.Linear);
```

text "your score" is written with pixel shader and linear filter

text "high score" is writte only with linear filter
 but it is stil sharp

[image: my text]

Comment: It would be helpful to see your font and the end result. Can you add some images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's an 8 months old question, but maybe your are still interested in the answer. Or at least someone with the same problem will be.

To have smooth fonts, I use free type fonts, and I create them in my loading screen. For that you need an asset manager.

Usually I create my asset manager in my main activty :

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game implements ApplicationListener {
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    public AssetManager assets;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        assets = new AssetManager();

        this.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
    }
}
```

And in the loading screen I create the fonts with any size, based on a .ttf file :

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen{
    final MyGdxGame game;

    public LoadingScreen(final MyGdxGame gam){
        game = gam;

        FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
        game.assets.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
        game.assets.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

        FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter size1Params = new FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
        size1Params.fontFileName = "Fonts/calibri.ttf";         
        size1Params.fontParameters.genMipMaps = true;                   
        size1Params.fontParameters.minFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
        size1Params.fontParameters.magFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;                        
        size1Params.fontParameters.size = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/18;
        game.assets.load("font1.ttf", BitmapFont.class, size1Params);

        FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter size2Params = new FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
        size2Params.fontFileName = "Fonts/calibri.ttf";         
        size2Params.fontParameters.genMipMaps = true;                   
        size2Params.fontParameters.minFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
        size2Params.fontParameters.magFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;                        
        size2Params.fontParameters.size = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6;
        game.assets.load("font2.ttf", BitmapFont.class, size2Params);
    }

}
```

With this method you can create very smooth font of any size. 
The trick to make them smooth is in these 3 lines :

```
        size2Params.fontParameters.genMipMaps = true;                   
        size2Params.fontParameters.minFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
        size2Params.fontParameters.magFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
```

Finally, when you need to use one of your font, you need to use :

```
game.assets.get("font1.ttf", BitmapFont.class)
```

Be careful with the name of your fonts. For the 2 fonts that I created in this example, `font1` and `font2`, I used a single .ttf file that is `calibri.ttf`, but when I call the created fonts in my code I need to call `font1.ttf` or `font2.ttf`, even if there are no such .ttf files in my asset.